# iphone app click delete crash

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, row

In my application when I press the delete row will crash. I tried to find a solution to this problem already, hope can help me solve it.

My code here:

FirstView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstView : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{




IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
IBOutlet UITextField *eventText;

NSArray *notificationArray;
NSMutableArray *Array;
   }
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *eventText;


- (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender;
@end
```

FirstView.m

```
#import "FirstView.h"


    @implementation FirstView
    @synthesize datePicker, eventText,tableview;

    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableview reloadData];
    }

    - (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender {
    [eventText resignFirstResponder];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit |        NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                                     fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [eventText text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

    [self.tableview reloadData];

    }
    // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically     and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
     /*
     - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
    }
    */


    // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a    nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    eventText.delegate = self; 
    Array = [notificationArray mutableCopy];

    [super viewDidLoad];
     }

     #pragma mark -
     #pragma mark Table view data source

      - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
      }


     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
      }


      // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      }

    // Configure the cell...

    notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:notif.alertBody];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[notif.fireDate description]];

    return cell;
}
     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    [Array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
/*
     // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
     }
*/
      - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField { 
    [eventText resignFirstResponder]; 
    return YES; 
} 
        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
      }

     - (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    datePicker = nil;
        eventText = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

the crash log here.

```
2011-04-12 13:27:26.860 SMS Timer[2050:207] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:995
2011-04-12 13:27:26.863 SMS Timer[2050:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dca5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f1e313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00d82ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x000b53bb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x00338e8b -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 8420
    5   UIKit                               0x00327cf8 -[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 56
    6   SMS Timer                           0x00003414 -[FirstView tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] + 189
    7   UIKit                               0x00325037 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 101
    8   UIKit                               0x002ba4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    9   UIKit                               0x0034a799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                               0x0034cc2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    11  UIKit                               0x0034b7d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    12  UIKit                               0x002deded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    13  UIKit                               0x002bfc37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    14  UIKit                               0x002c4f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x01722992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00dab944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0bcf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d08f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00d08840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00d08761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x017211c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x01721289 GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x002c8c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  SMS Timer                           0x00002754 main + 102
    25  SMS Timer                           0x000026e5 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    [Array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

//TRy to set your count for this line
//[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];IF you are getting this proper after deleting the cell, then it won;t crash.Since you are deleting the cell but not updating the count so still it return 5 intend of 4 after deleting the data.
[self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Hope that works...Lets give hand on this

Comment: In the same method just try to print the array once you delete it ie. [self.tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

Comment: can gave the simple mah?..i really donno how to do ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Its clear from the crash log that "invalid number of rows in section 0" is the cause of the crash. Pls debug your application to see the rows for the sections each time you edit the cells. It will then help you to identify the cause.

Comment: i still don know how to get this crash.i have try use debug to see the rows.but i no understand what is tat.

Comment: i get this.0x94bf514c  <+0000>  mov    $0xc0025,%eax
0x94bf5151  <+0005>  call   0x94b94378 <_sysenter_trap>
0x94bf5156  <+0010>  jae    0x94bf5166 <__kill+26>
0x94bf5158  <+0012>  call   0x94bf515d <__kill+17>
0x94bf515d  <+0017>  pop    %edx
0x94bf515e  <+0018>  mov    0xbab2787(%edx),%edx
0x94bf5164  <+0024>  jmp    *%edx
0x94bf5166  <+0026>  ret